# using cffeed at rss feed

Tags: coldfusion, rss, cffeed

I am using cffeed for making an rss feed, but I have problems using the  tag for images. Is there anyone who can help me with that?

Another problem is making the  a string while the input comes from an 'int' field. Is there a simple way to solve that problem?

I bases my code on the article in here:
[Images in rss feed using ColdFusion and CFFeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734840/images-in-rss-feed-using-coldfusion-and-cffeed)

thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a little more detailed about what problems you have. So you have problems using the tag for images. What kind of problem? What are you trying? What is the result? What would you want the result to be? Posting some short code extracts in the question might also be a good idea to attract better answers.

Comment: Also, keep each posting to a single question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the second part of your problem, try:

```
#javaCast( "string", value )#
```

where value is the numeric that should be a string. Coldfusion is typeless, but when it encounters a value that could be made into a numeric it will do so. Hence the javaCast which explicitly sets the value to be a String.